# Very small labels in HERE Maps

Tags: here-api

As per the HERE Maps JS API platform.createDefaultLayers, by changing the ppi parameter, the font size will be adjusted. But, I'm unable to see any difference in the map. As can be seen in the screenshot below, the labels are too small. How can I make the labels readable in a 7inch 1080p display?

```html
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers(512,  320 );
  
 //Step 2: initialize a map
 var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('slide-map'),
    defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
    center: {lat:27.7279, lng:85.3284},
    zoom: 18,
    pixelRatio: 1
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed defaultLayers.vector.normal.map to defaultLayers.raster.normal.map, the tileSize and ppi parameters started affecting the label size.

```html
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers(512,  320 );
  
 //Step 2: initialize a map
 var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('slide-map'),
    defaultLayers.raster.normal.map,{
    center: {lat:27.7279, lng:85.3284},
    zoom: 18,
    pixelRatio: 1
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For carnav scheme and normal.day.custom only normal ppi is accepted.
See: https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-base-basetile.html#resource-base-basetile__includes-query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Here is some way to adjust tile size depending on the device pixel ratio.

```
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
      tileSize: devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 512 : 256,
      ppi: devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 320 : 72
    });

    // Step 3: initialize the map
    var map = new H.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'),
      defaultLayers.normal.map,
      {
        center: { lat: 47.056, lng: 2.350 },
        zoom: 6,
        pixelRatio: Math.min(devicePixelRatio, 2)  // capping at 2 since some devices have a pixel ratio above 2 
      }
    );
```

for more details please check this-

https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-base-basetile.html#resource-base-basetile__includes-query-parameters

Comment: I tried this, but this is giving me the following error:
__Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined__

Comment: When I changed defaultLayers.vector.normal.map to defaultLayers.raster.normal.map, the tileSize and ppi parameters started affecting the label size.